# Android passing hebrew letters via Json to server based Spring MVC appear as gibberish

Tags: android, json, spring-mvc

Im building an Android app where i need to pass hebrew (UTF-8?) letters via Json to the server and these letters appear as gibberish instead. Tried looking for info on the web but no luck there. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

in the JSONParser.java class:

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    Log.d("params in json",String.valueOf(params));
    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

I had the same problem, found the solution, hope it can still help.
in the line:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));
```

I didn't have the `utf-8` defined.
I used post method, if you use get method then the line is:

```
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
```